# how do i network VMs when only one IP available ? (proxmox)

Tags: nginx, networking, linux-networking, proxmox, nginx-reverse-proxy

sorry if the question has already been asked but cannot find an answer for my usecase.

The problem:

we have a server in a datacenter colocation, this server is connected to the DC network and has access to two IPs, one (10.8.x.x) that is only accessible if AT the datacenter or through the VPN they provided.
they also provided us with a public IP 185.18.x.x and this one has access to the internet.

on this server i have installed proxmox, to separate the server into VMs for the different services we're going to host. the goal is to have all VMs be able to access the internet but only one of them will have an NGINX proxy to forward the HTTP requests to the appropriate VM.

bonus point if i can get to SSH to the VMs.

basically trying to make my own sub-network with the IP i'm given.

can anyone please give me a some advice on if it's doable and some advice on stuff to research or some kind of answer ?
thank you all !

Answer (score -1):

Technically you *can* do that: the only accessible IP goes into the VM which routes the network for VMs and the host. However, you may imagine how brittle this setup is, so I advise you strongly against that.

Have at least *two* accessible IP addresses: one for the host and other one for the VM which performs NAT and/or reverse proxy for other VMs. Ideally, you need at least *three* IPs; third one goes for the IPMI BMC of the server.

If you only have a single usable IP, better do NAT on the host, but in that case it is useful to have a dedicated container for the reverse proxy.

Comment: Your answer is wrong as it is ignorant to what the OP states. There is no need for additional host level public IP's - the OP has access to an IP for the host that is internal only to the provider and he can use a VPN to get access to it. This is actually a surprisingly good setup (that few ISP's offer) and it totally means that neither the host NOR THE BMC need to have public IP addresses if they can be part of an internal admin network with VPN access.

Comment: I probably used the word "public" in not a common meaning as "publicly routable IP" but as "IP that is does not belong to a network internal to the host".